# How to remove item from laravel query result and get it?

Tags: laravel, collections

In Laravel project I am making a database query

```
$addresses = DB::table('residences')->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

I want to get one address from that query result, if it exists, where 'id' field equals to 10 for example. But I want to remove that address from $addresses query result simultaneously. Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `reject()` method on the `$addresses` [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-reject), i.e:

```php
$my_result = false;
$addresses = $addresses->reject(function ($value, $key) use (&$my_result) {
    if($value->id == 10){
        $my_result = $value;
        return true
    }
    return false;
});
```